# How to access a field of a schema in OpenAPI?

Tags: rest, openapi

I have the below OpenAPI 3.1 schema definition for Customer:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Customer:
      title: Customer
      type: object
      properties:
        customer_id: 
          type: integer
          description: customer ID
          format: int32
          example: 10293847

        email:
          type: string
          description: customer email
          example: john@email.com

        address:
          type: string
          description: customer address
          example: 123 Street Name, Apt 456, City, State - Zip
      required:
        - customer_id
        - email
        - address
```

To return a list of `customer_id` I can do:

```yaml
paths:
  /customer/all:
    get:
      tags:
        - customer
      summary: Retrieve list of customer IDs
      description: Retrieve the IDs of all existing customers
      operationId: getCustomersById
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  customer_id:
                    type: integer
                    format: int32
```

But this does not reference the Customer schema.

Is there a way I can reference the `customer_id` property of Customer schema in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field/s which are shared should be declared as `schema`s and referred to by other `schema`s.

For example the following definition of `CustomerId` which is then referred to from `Customer`:

```
components:
  schemas:
     CustomerId: # definition to share
      type: integer
      description: customer ID
      format: int32
      example: 10293847
     Customer:
      title: Customer
      type: object
      properties:
        customer_id:
          schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/CustomerId' # referring back to the initial/shared definition
        email:
          type: string
          description: customer email
          example: john@email.com
        address:
          type: string
          description: customer address
          example: 123 Street Name, Apt 456, City, State - Zip
      required:
        - customer_id
        - email
        - address
```

Sadly these definitions cannot be shared between `schema` definitions and `parameter` definitions. The `CustomerId` has to be defined again amongst the parameters.

The following full definition produces what appears to be the correct Java.

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Simple API
  description: A simple API to illustrate OpenAPI inheritance

paths:
  /customer:
    put:
      tags:
        - customer
      summary: Create or update a customer
      description: Create or update a customer
      operationId: putCustomers
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Customer'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/CustomerId'
  
  /customer/{customerId}:
    get:
      tags:
        - customer
      summary: read a single customer
      description: Read a single customer
      operationId: getCustomer
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/CustomerId'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Customer'

  /customer/all:
    get:
      tags:
        - customer
      summary: Retrieve list of customer IDs
      description: Retrieve the IDs of all existing customers
      operationId: getAllCustomerIds
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/CustomerId'
components:
  schemas:
     CustomerId:
      type: integer
      description: customer ID
      format: int32
      example: 10293847
     Customer:
      title: Customer
      type: object
      properties:
        customer_id:
          schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/CustomerId' # referring back to the initial/shared definition
        email:
          type: string
          description: customer email
          example: john@email.com
        address:
          type: string
          description: customer address
          example: 123 Street Name, Apt 456, City, State - Zip
      required:
        - customer_id
        - email
        - address

  parameters:
    CustomerId:
      name: customerId
      in: path
      required: true
      description: customer IDa
      schema:
        type: integer
        description: customer IDb
        format: int32
        example: 10293847

  responses:
    400Error:
      description: Invalid request
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object 
            properties:
              message:
                type: string
```

**Generated Java Customer**

```
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-04-13T17:11:44.093546300+01:00[Europe/London]")
public class Customer {

  @JsonProperty("customer_id")
  private Integer customerId;

  @JsonProperty("email")
  private String email;

  @JsonProperty("address")
  private String address;

  public Customer customerId(Integer customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * customer ID
   * @return customerId
  */
  @NotNull 
  @Schema(name = "customer_id", example = "10293847", description = "customer ID", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
  public Integer getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
  }

  public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
  }

  public Customer email(String email) {
    this.email = email;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * customer email
   * @return email
  */
  @NotNull 
  @Schema(name = "email", example = "john@email.com", description = "customer email", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public Customer address(String address) {
    this.address = address;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * customer address
   * @return address
  */
  @NotNull 
  @Schema(name = "address", example = "123 Street Name, Apt 456, City, State - Zip", description = "customer address", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
  public String getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Customer customer = (Customer) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.customerId, customer.customerId) &&
        Objects.equals(this.email, customer.email) &&
        Objects.equals(this.address, customer.address);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(customerId, email, address);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class Customer {\n");
    sb.append("    customerId: ").append(toIndentedString(customerId)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    email: ").append(toIndentedString(email)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    address: ").append(toIndentedString(address)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }
}
```

**Generated Java Api**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.example.demo.openapi.model.Customer;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.ParameterIn;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.ArraySchema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;

@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-04-13T17:11:44.093546300+01:00[Europe/London]")
@Validated
@Tag(name = "customer", description = "the customer API")
public interface CustomerApi {

    default CustomerApiDelegate getDelegate() {
        return new CustomerApiDelegate() {};
    }

    /**
     * GET /customer/all : Retrieve list of customer IDs
     * Retrieve the IDs of all existing customers
     *
     * @return successful operation (status code 200)
     */
    @Operation(
        operationId = "getAllCustomerIds",
        summary = "Retrieve list of customer IDs",
        description = "Retrieve the IDs of all existing customers",
        tags = { "customer" },
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "successful operation", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = Integer.class)))
            })
        }
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/customer/all",
        produces = { "application/json" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<List<Integer>> getAllCustomerIds(
        
    ) {
        return getDelegate().getAllCustomerIds();
    }


    /**
     * GET /customer/{customerId} : read a single customer
     * Read a single customer
     *
     * @param customerId customer IDa (required)
     * @return successful operation (status code 200)
     */
    @Operation(
        operationId = "getCustomer",
        summary = "read a single customer",
        description = "Read a single customer",
        tags = { "customer" },
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "successful operation", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = Customer.class))
            })
        }
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/customer/{customerId}",
        produces = { "application/json" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<Customer> getCustomer(
        @Parameter(name = "customerId", description = "customer IDa", required = true, in = ParameterIn.PATH) @PathVariable("customerId") Integer customerId
    ) {
        return getDelegate().getCustomer(customerId);
    }


    /**
     * PUT /customer : Create or update a customer
     * Create or update a customer
     *
     * @param customer  (required)
     * @return successful operation (status code 200)
     */
    @Operation(
        operationId = "putCustomers",
        summary = "Create or update a customer",
        description = "Create or update a customer",
        tags = { "customer" },
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "successful operation", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = Integer.class))
            })
        }
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.PUT,
        value = "/customer",
        produces = { "application/json" },
        consumes = { "application/json" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<Integer> putCustomers(
        @Parameter(name = "Customer", description = "", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody Customer customer
    ) {
        return getDelegate().putCustomers(customer);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `/customer/all` endpoint returns only the list of IDs, not the schemas. Is there another API endpoint declared that lets you get the data for an individual customer? It might be `/customer/{id}` or something like that.

Make the request to that endpoint for the customer that you want the full schema for.

Comment: With `/customer/all` I want to return an array of only the `customer_id` field in the `customer` schema, not a dedicated object, and definitely not the entire schema. 
Even for something like a GET `/customer/{id}`, I wouldn't want to access the full schema - in this case I would like to reference `email` and `address` of the `customer` schema.